# If .htaccess redirects domainroot to a localized start page, should the domain root (which should be canonical) be in the sitemap.xml?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, localization, sitemap

When you host a webpage, e.g., `https://mydomain.example` and `.htaccess` already takes care of the rewrite from *www* to without *www* and from *http* to *https* and it is also rewriting with `RewriteRule ^$ https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html [R=301,L]` to
`https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html` (this file obviously holds the actual HTML code) and you have also other pages `https://mydomain.example/en/page2.html` , `https://mydomain.example/en/page3.html` etc.
and a similar set of pages for another language
`https://mydomain.example/de/page1.html` (with just the same content in e.g. german language), `https://mydomain.example/de/page2.html` , `https://mydomain.example/de/page3.html` etc.

then Google gives some advice in *[Tell Google about localized versions of your page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions)*.

I did that, but I did not figure out whether I should keep `https://mydomain.example` and */* or `https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html` in my sitemap.

Now the incoming external backlinks all point to `https://mydomain.example`. This is the reason why I put `<link rel="canonical"  href="https://mydomain.example">` in the header of `https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html`

The google search console indexed `https://mydomain.example` correctly and put `https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html` into the not indexed category due to Duplicate without user-selected canonical. It has meanwhile also disappeared from there.

Only recently google chrome lighthouse has added a SEO error for my setup "Document does not have a valid rel=canonicalPoints to the domain's root URL (the homepage), instead of an equivalent page of content".

Should `https://mydomain.example` and `https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html` both be in my sitemap?

Also, should I

a.) change the setup to make `https://mydomain.example/en/page1.html` my canoncial page? or

b.) to make `https://mydomain.example/en/` my canonical startup and work with a DirectoryIndex to point to `page1.html` ? or

c.) leave `https://mydomain.example` as the canonical page since the incoming links go there?

Please note that I found a relevant answer to my question (see below), but it is very old and the accepted answer was never upvoted, so I am unsure if it (still) applies:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963185/which-url-should-be-in-sitemap-xml-when-redirecting-request*

Edit: Trying to make my question more clear I made substantial edit. Sorry for any invonvenience caused.

Answer (score 2):

Your sitemap should contain the URLs that you want search engines to index. It should not contain any URLs that:

1. Redirect
2. Are not canonical

[Google says](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap#general-guidelines):

> **List only canonical URLs** in your sitemaps. If you have multiple versions of a page, list in the sitemap only the one you prefer to appear in search results. If you have multiple versions of your site (for example, www and non-www), decide which is your preferred site, and put the sitemap there, and add `rel=canonical` or redirects on the other site.

Therefore the following URLs should be included in your sitemap:

- `https://mydomain.example/en/home.html`
- `https://mydomain.example/de/home.html`
- `https://mydomain.example/es/home.html`

And the following URLs should be omitted from your sitemap:

- `https://mydomain.example/`
- `http://mydomain.example/`
- `https://www.mydomain.example/`

---

As an aside, I would recommend removing `home.html` from your URLs. `https://mydomain.example/en/` is a cleaner, simpler, more user-friendly URL compared to `https://mydomain.example/en/home.html`. Default documents like `index.html` and `home.html` should never appear in URLs to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply. Until now I had https://mydomain.example as the canonical url. And all my incoming external backlinks point to there. Is it still recommended for me to now change the canonical tag to point to https://mydomain.example/en/home.html ? (there might be a seo loss?) And so it can be that the canonical url is never displayed to the user? (Sorry it seems I still have to learn a few things here). So your recommendation is to use DirectoryIndex to display the home.html content?

Comment: If you are adding languages to your site, you need to have the separate languages on separate URLs for SEO.  It is possible to have the English version on `/` and the Spanish version on `/es/`.  If you moved the English version to `/en/` it might have a short term SEO drop, but it would recover and not be a long term problem. You'd want to have a language chooser of some sort on the `/` URL.

Comment: You can use `DirectoryIndex` to serve `home.html` is the default, but I'd recommend renaming `home.html` to `index.html` because 99% of web servers use `index.html` without any additional configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry, I tried to improve my original post to make my question more clear. Trying to improve the sitemap and .htaccess if needed.